# JavaScript calculator error

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am still learning on how to build a calculator. The calculator is not working but I don't know what wrong with it. Please help me out.

**Code**

```js
var myDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
function calculatedose () { 
var weight = document.paeform.weight.value 
var dose1 = document.paeform.dose1.value 
var strengthmg = document.paeform.strengthmg.value 
var strengthml = document.paeform.strengthml.value 
if (weight > 0 && dose1 > 0 && strengthmg > 0 && strengthml > 0) { 
    var finaldose = weight*dose1*(strengthmg/strenghml) 
    document.paeform.dose.value = finaldose 
  } 
}
```

```html
<form name="paeform"> 
Weight(kg): <input name="weight" size="10" type="text" /><br /> 
Dosage(mg/kg): <input name="height" size="10" type="text" /><br /> 
Liquid formulation(mg): <input name="strengthmg" size="10" type="text" /><br /> 
Liquid formulation(ml): <input name="strengthml" size="10" type="text" /><br /> 
<input type="button" value="Calculate Dose" onclick="calculatedose()" /><br /> 
Amount perdose (ml): <input name="dose" size="10" type="text" /><br /> 
<input type="reset" value="Reset" /></form>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. It's very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```js
var myDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
function calculatedose() {
var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value || "0";
var dose1 = document.getElementById('dose1').value || "0";
var strengthmg = document.getElementById('strengthmg').value || "0";
var strengthml = document.getElementById('strengthml').value || "0";
weight = parseInt(weight);
    dose1 = parseInt(dose1);
    strengthmg = parseInt(strengthmg);
    strengthml = parseInt(strengthml);
if (weight > 0 && dose1 > 0 && strengthmg > 0 && strengthml > 0) {
    var finaldose = weight * dose1 * (strengthmg / strengthml)
    document.getElementById('dose').value = finaldose;
}
}
```

```html
<form name="paeform">
    Weight(kg): <input id="weight" size="10" type="text" /><br />
    Dosage(mg/kg): <input id="dose1" size="10" type="text" /><br />
    Liquid formulation(mg): <input id="strengthmg" size="10" type="text" /><br />
    Liquid formulation(ml): <input id="strengthml" size="10" type="text" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Calculate Dose" onclick="calculatedose()" /><br />
    Amount perdose (ml): <input id="dose" size="10" type="text" /><br />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```